# Not sure why results are transposing from RecordSet in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I am a newbie at using `Recordsets` and need some assistance as to why the data is transposing from the Database to Excel.  I believe its in the following code, but not sure.

```
For iRow = 0 To intNumReturned - 1
    For iCol = 0 To intNumColumns - 1
        Debug.Print rsRecords(iCol, iRow)
    Next iCol
Next iRow
```

Result from SQL String, which is expected:

```
PROCESSOR | ACCOUNT NUMBER | LOAN AMOUNT | ORIGNATION DATE
ZJE         xxxxxxx          XXXXXX.XX      2018-01-01
ZJE         xxxxxxx          XXXXXX.XX      2018-02-06
```

How the data gets placed into the Excel Sheet:

```
PROCESSOR | ACCOUNT NUMBER | LOAN AMOUNT | ORIGNATION DATE
ZJE         ZJE              ZJE           ZJE
acct no     acct no          acct no       acct no
loan amt    loan amt         loan amt      loan amt                               
Org Date    Org Date         Org Date      org date
```

Below is the code i am currently using minus the Connection and SQL Strings:

```
Sub RunSearch()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim connStr As String, strSQL As String
    Dim begQ1 As String, endQ1 As String, begQ2 As String, endQ2 As String, begQ3 As String, endQ3 As String, begQ4 As String, endQ4 As String
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim rsRecords As Variant
    Dim intNumReturned As Long, intNumColumns As Long, iCol As Long, iRow As Long, fldCount As Long, i As Long, rsCount As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsVol = wb.Sheets("Volume By Processor")
    Set wsDE = wb.Sheets("DE")
    Set quarterYear = wsDE.Range("Quarter_Year")
    Set Q = wsDE.Range("Quarter")
    Set fDate = wsDE.Range("From_Date")
    Set tDate = wsDE.Range("To_Date")

Do While Not rs.EOF
    rs.MoveNext
    rsRecords = rs.GetRows
    intNumReturned = UBound(rsRecords, 2) + 1
    intNumColumns = UBound(rsRecords, 1) + 1
Loop

    For iRow = 0 To intNumReturned - 1
        For iCol = 0 To intNumColumns - 1
            Debug.Print rsRecords(iCol, iRow)
        Next iCol
    Next iRow


'\\\NEED TO FIGURE OUT NUMBER OF RECORDS TO
'\\\DEFINE LAST ROW/COLUMN OF RANGE????  PROBABLY A
'\\\SEPARATE QUESTION ON SO
    wsVol.Range("B3:E1800") = rsRecords

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
```

I am expecting the result in the Excel sheet to match the the output from the SQL String any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into `Range.CopyFromRecordset`; there is no need to iterate the results or store them in an array.

Comment: Moreover, `GetRows` *in itself* doesn't require iterating the recordset - it does yield a weirdly-shaped (transposed) array though, as you noticed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  This is now working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want go to another "entry" of the recordset you can use ".MoveNext" method.

It will be something like this:

```
rsRecords.MoveFirst 'In this line you will back for the first entry
For iRow = 0 To intNumReturned - 1
     For iCol = 0 To intNumColumns - 1
         Debug.Print rsRecords(iCol)
     Next iCol
rsRecords.MoveNext 'In this line you move to the next "row" as you want
Next iRow
```

Comment: You are already using MoveNext to get the number of entries, so first you will need to include "rsRecords.MoveFirst" before the loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I am going to keep this for future reference as I'm sure I will need it again.